# Automation of monthly reports in R using data from Blynk Server

Tags: r, string, csv, variables, filenames

I'd like to pull the current system date as a variable and use it as an identifier to point to the right file name. This variable should be inserted as part of the string clarifying the file path within the `read.csv` command. I'm unsure how to use this variable as part of the string within a command. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something along these lines:

```
var_date = Sys.Date()

var_file_name = paste0("name_of_the_file_", var_date, ".txt")
# "name_of_the_file_2020-10-29.txt"

read.csv(file = var_file_name)
```

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted.